# Spring Boot MessageConverter using JakartaXmlBindAnnotationModule cannot resolve individual @XMLElements property names

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, jaxb, fasterxml

Using the following configuration with a Spring Boot Application only partially unmarshals XML.

```
@Configuration
class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(
            List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(0, new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(
                new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
                        .defaultUseWrapper(false)
                        .createXmlMapper(true)
                        .build()
                        .registerModule(new JakartaXmlBindAnnotationModule())
        ));
    }
}
```

The classes being used as the controller's @RequestBody type were generated based on an XSD file using the XJC tool.

Here is the signature of the Spring Boot controller:

```
@PostMapping(value="/method", consumes= MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
            produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseType> Method(@RequestBody RequestTypeGeneratedByXJC request) {

}
```

Some of the classes generated by XJC (including the one used as the @RequestBody type of the controller) contain some properties with the following annotations.

```
@XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name="Name1"),
        @XmlElement(name="Name2")
})
protected List<Object> name1OrName2
```

When a new request is handled by the HTTP message converters they are unable to resolve these particular property names and the properties are left null or the unmarshalling fails with  "Unrecognizable field" when `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` is set. Other properities that do not have these @XMLElements model group annotations unmarshal correctly and contain valid values. Based on documentation I have seen the only requirement to get JAXB style annotations to work properly with Spring Boot is to have the Jakarta dependencies on the classpath and include an HTTP message converter with the JakartaXmlBindAnnotationModule registered as shown. Since some properties are being unmarshalled properly it seems the problem is somehow specific to the unmarshalling of the @XMLElement model group annotations.

The XML being sent to the controller method can have a structure with 0 or more of any of the XMLElement types such as:

```
<Element>
  <Name1>A Name</Name1>
  <Name2>Another Name</Name1>
</Element>
```

Which is represented in the XSD being used with XJC as:

```
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
   <xs:element name="Name1" type="Name1Type"/>
   <xs:element name="Name2" type="Name1Type"/>
</xs:choice>
```

Do I need to set additional configurations to allow it to resolve these types of properties? With the current configuration and based on the error messages it seems to expect the property to have a single element name such as `Name1` and `Name2` and cannot determine that `name1OrName2` maps to the elements with either the name `Name1` or `Name2`. Or maybe there is a totally different approach to allow a Spring Boot REST controller to map XML to a JAXB annotated class. From the documentation, it seems as if registering the `JakartaXmlBindAnnotationModule` should be enough to allow the FasterXML library to understand the JAXB annotations and since choice elements are common it seems like this should be easy to achieve.

As an alternative it would work if the classes were generated with separate properties for each of the choice elements. The following documentation seems to indicate this can be done using the `choiceContentProperty` setting. However, if tried adding this as a globalBinding attribute passed to XJC, but setting this to "true" or "false" seemed to have no impact on how the properties were generated.

6.12.7.2. Bind single occurrence choice group to a choice content property

https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-binding/3.0/jakarta-xml-binding-spec-3.0.html#xmlelements

Thanks.

Comment: Also the goal is simply to get a Spring Boot controller working with a @RequestBody unmarshalled to the classes autogenerated by XJC with those JAXB based annotations. If there's a way to accomplish this without configuring the message converters that would answer would be useful also.

Comment: Based on the XJC documentation the choiceContentProperty appears to control whether choice element of a model group are grouped into a single property or separate properties. However setting this property to "true" or "false" seems to have no impact on the classes being generated. If there is a way to have XJC generate separate properties that would be useful also.

Comment: "The classes being used were generated based on an XSD file using XJC and contain properties with the following annotations which the current configuration is not able to resolve the property names of." - I didn't understand the statement. Please explain clearly (divide the sentence into several ones)